# How to remove double quote from a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove the double quotes inside the string but was not able to do so.

```
var productName = "300" Table";
console.log(productName);
var newTemp = productName.replace('"', /'/g);
console.log(newTemp);
var requestData = JSON.stringify({
        'product_name': productName,
        'page_url': newTemp
    });

var obj = JSON.parse(requestData);
console.log(obj);
```

It is throwing an error in the second line.

Comment: If you are trying to make a test case you need to put a \ in front of the `"` after 300

Comment: Read the documentation for `replace` one more time, a little more carefully. Read the documentation for string literals one more time, a little more carefully. Also, why are you stringifying the object, and then immediately parsing it again?

Comment: You could split string on double quote and then join it back.. Or you could use urlEncode to encode a double quote, replace the encoded double quote, then decide the string back..

Comment: `var productName = "300" Table";` is a syntax error. It makes it hard to help you when we don't know for sure what your actual starting point (the actual string) is.

Answer (score 1):

From your coding pattern I think you need something like this just escape the inner double quotes(`"`) with a slash(`\`) when you assign string to **productName** variable. Then replace the occurrence of double quotes with nothing i.e `productName.replace(/"/g, "")`

**Full Code**: Shorten after removing unnecessary `JSON.stringify()` & `JSON.parse()`

```js
var productName = "300\" Table";
var newTemp = productName.replace(/"/g, "");
console.log(`old productName = ${productName}, newTemp after replace " = ${newTemp}`);
var requestData = {
  'product_name': productName,
  'page_url': newTemp
};
console.log(requestData );
```

**See Escape notation on MDN**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String